# Accent circonflexe sur le O de « construire »

Tags: orthographe

Je viens de tomber sur le mot « construire » dans un livre orthographié « cônstruire ». Je n'avais jamais vu cette écriture et, après quelques recherches, il semble que celle-ci n'existe pas. Est-ce une faute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, c'est une faute. Il n'y a jamais eu une telle écriture du mot selon les premiers exemples qu'on peut voir [dans le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/construire).

Le mot vient du latin « [cōnstruō](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/construo) ». Le macron indique [une voyelle longue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_(diacritique)#Latin). Peut-être que quelqu'un a mal interprété ce fait. Mais il en est de même pour beaucoup de mots ayant la racine « con- », dont « [cōnsciō](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/conscio#Latin) » (*connaître*), ce qui ne fait pourtant pas qu'on indique aujourd'hui cette propriété vocalique qui a depuis été perdue dans ce morphème-là.

Comment: P.S. Sens-toi libre à corriger mes propres fautes s'il y en a :)